# Unable to force a user notification to be sent when a modern page is added to a list view

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, alert, modern-pages

I am working on a classic sharepoint online team site. and i have a list view (named "News") which shows site pages that are linked to a specific term (named "News") inside a managed metadata site column (named "Category"), as follow:-

[image]

**now i want to define a user alert when a site page is created and it is linked to the News term**. so i defined the following user alert:-

[image]

but i am facing an issue. Now let say i create a new site page, and i link it to the "News" term, then i will get a user alert email, which is great. but if i modify the site page and i chnage the "Category" to another term (other than the "News") i will also get an email that the page has changed. now i think the problem, is that my user alert will send an email on any change that is done to any page inside the list view , even if the action means that the page will no longer be shown inside the list view.. 
so i am not sure how i can fix this? now i change the user alert's "Change Type" setting from "All Changes" to "New items are added", but this will never send any user notification. i think this is related to how modern pages internally work, as they will be created before saving them and before being assigned to a managed metadata value.. so is there a way to achieve what i am looking for using user notifications ?

Answer (score 0):

How did you create a new site page, and link it to the "News" term?

Per my test, I cannot receive the email notification even I create the new site page and set the column value to News.

To work around, you can create the workflow with send an email action and start the workflow automatically. Add the If value equals value condition to check if the column value equals News.

Comment: now in my case i have created a new custom site content type which inherit from "Site Pages">> i add the "Category" managed metadata column to it >> then i add the custom content type to my "Site Pages" list >> finally i set the custom CT as the defualt CT for the "Site Pages" list. then i create a new modern page using the "Add a page" link which can be found under the gear icon... for me adding a page and assign it the "News" term will send a notification without any issue...